# How to fix Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server: Unauthorized in Android studio

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, gitlab

I have one project on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) and I worked with it for the last few days!

Now i want **`pull`** project on my home PC but show me below error :

```
Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
        at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.handleInput(GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:34)
        at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassApp.main(GitNativeSshAskPassApp.java:30)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendRequest(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:231)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:90)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178)
```

My android studio version is **3.4** !

Comment: Did you try pulling from the terminal ?

Comment: @theapache64, when pulling from terminal show me below error : `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: @theapache64, i added my public key into gitlab, but show me error!! please see this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBxjp.png

Comment: I think you haven't added the SSH key of your **Home PC**

Comment: @theapache64, i added this, please see above image. i added this and work for my. but after some time show me above error!!!

Comment: I'm getting the same error today (worked for years...): cannot even GIT fetch inside Android Studio 3.4 neither from Github nor from Gitlab.
Fetch and push of the same repository work from command line (where I enter keyfile password for every command) AND from IntelliJ Idea, when I opened the same project (and also was asked for a password on fetch).

Conclusion: Looks like previously stored passwords are incorrect now... and need to be re-entered. Or some other problem of Android Studio 3.4...

BTW Did you update Java recently?
This is the only possible cause that I can think of...

Comment: Get this same error after updating from AS 3.3 to 3.4 on windows. No issue with same update on Ubuntu. Can fetch using git bash. Tried changing to "Do not remember passwords", and on restart exact same behaviour

Comment: I have same problem when update Android Studio3.3 to Android Studio3.4
I use Android Stuidio Terminal to update or push code to Gitlab,maybe this is a bug of Android Studio3.4

Comment: @Jakewarton please check my answer below

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Managed to fix it like this:

AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Git -> SSH Executable and changed from `Native` to `Built-in` and it started working.

Edit: this is for Android Studio 3.4, for 3.6 Volodymyr has an answer below.

Comment: Maybe because Beta 1 just go released? Try the solution Volodymyr provided. Didn't get to test AS 3.5 at all yet.

Comment: Not working for me. Even when added the key via `ssh-add`, Android Studio doesn't pick it up.

Comment: It *is* working in IntelliJ though. When testing a clone, a dialog asking for the password appears (looks like the "Built-In" variant). But Android Studio does not show this dialog.

Comment: what is the difference between these 2?

Comment: This setting doesn't appear in Android Studio 3.6 for Mac. Is there a different setting in the Mac version?

Comment: What the Preferences, where is it??

Answer (score 208):

Enabling credentials helper worked for me, using Android Studio 3.6.2 on Windows 10

`AndroidStudio -> File -> Settings -> Git ->  Use credential helper`

Comment: This one worked for me with android studio 2021.1.1 beta 5

Comment: I am using Bitbucket and this worked

Comment: worked in Bumblebee

Comment: This fixed it for me - I could clone in cmd line but not in android studio. Thanks!

Comment: Worked in Chipmunk

Comment: Works for Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Comment: This one worked for the Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1. Thanks.

Comment: Works for chipmunk.

Comment: This is the right solution but it works ONLY if you're logged in in the console. If not, navigate to your project, do `git pull` and then put your credentials (username & access token as a password if 2FA enabled)

Comment: this is work for me in window 10 in android studio version Bumblebee.

Comment: For Android Studio Chipmunk: File->Version Control->Git->Use credential helper

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by adding SSH private key to the ssh-agent in the command line:

```
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Also, check if Git settings are set to Native

`Settings --> Version Control --> Git` in the `SSH executable:` dropdown, choose `Native`

**EDIT**
It was fixed in the latest version 3.6.1 of Android Studio
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-361-available.html

Comment: Had the same problem after updating to the new Android Studio 3.6.0, and just added the ssh line into the command line and after that it worked

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue,clone my project from gitlab and save credential.helper with command in terminal:

```
   git config credential.helper store
```

and

```
 git fetch
```

[image]

Comment: after trying this getting below error, 

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

Answer (score 28):

Use these steps to git over HTTPS not SSH:

1. `git config credential.helper store`
2. You'll be requested the credentials username/token or pass.
3. Check this in Preferences > GIT > Use Credential Helper
   [image: The checkbox Use Credential Helper]

Answer (score 21):

Here's what worked for me, I am running different ids on bitbucket and github

1. Enabled Credentials Helper
   `AndroidStudio -> File -> Settings -> Git ->  Use credential helper`
2. Ran `git config credential.helper store`
3. Ran `git fetch` through console once

Comment: it worked well on azure

Answer (score 11):

**File -> Invalidate Cache And Restart** worked in my case

Comment: I wish I had tried that before loosing my time with other solutions...

Comment: That works, thanks! Probably, Jetbrains has hired some Microsoft developers and they started to implement Microsoft's "reboot to work" culture.

Answer (score 7):

This Error seems to appear if your SSH Key Pair is secured with a password

The **native** SSH Executebale can not prompt you for your password in Android Studio afaik, so authentication will fail if the credentials are not provided otherwise.

Using the **Built-in** SSH Executable will let you enter your password via a prompt in Android studio.

The Answer provided by Adrian worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the similar. Here are the steps that resolve my problem.

1. Go To https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
2. Create a app password
3. Then execute `git config credential.helper store`
4. Run `git fetch`
5. Then it will ask for password, enter the password that created from bitbucket console.

Then it work.

Comment: the only solution that works.

Comment: Thank you for saving my time

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue with Bitbucket and as they say Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication. If you're using bitbucket here's what you need to do.

details : https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231

1. create an app password
   [how to create app passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/)

Allow the the appropriate permissions and create the password. once the password is generated you need to store it for later use somewhere else because you won't see it again.

2. Goto AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Git and tick the "Use credentials helper" and apply.
3. run "git fetch" and the credentials helper will popup , and enter the saved app password and viola!

**EDIT**

followed following url:

[how to use "git fetch" command](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/git-fetch)

[image: git fetch command]

```
git remote add origin "git link"
```

it will ask the password

follow this link https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

to create app password. and store it somewhere .It will require to place the password when asks.

```
git fetch
git pull origin master
```

that's all there you go.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward solution. Looks like bitbucket cloud no longer supports account password when using basic auth. for git over https.

Comment: where to type git fetch? I am using Mac. I need to import from bitbucket as fresh. What to do?

Answer (score 4):

file->setting->git-> SSH executable: dropdown, choose  built in

Answer (score 4):

In case you try to push from **Android Studio 4** or above into **Github** and get this error message you have to re login into **Github**.

```
Android Studio -> Setting-> GitHub
```

if you can't login using username and password
try to get a token from GitHub

https://github.com/settings/tokens

and then generate new token if you don't have one and login with **Token** just like the photo -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, don't use the shortcut(`git@github.com:/example/example.git`) provided by logging in to git, submit directly using the full repo address(`https://github.com/example/example.git`).

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem for my bitbucket account then I used terminal to get the exact error.

Below are my observations

```
1-git pull
fatal: Invalid credentials -- this was the error coming 
remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
```

After this I have to create app password from below link.

```
https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
```

2-After setting all permissions it will create a password for you

3-Then use this password in credential manager or in terminal when it will task.

This is the latest issue I observed and solved hope it may help anyone.

Comment: Oh, many thanks. It's a very helped me, bro. I face the same with BitBucket now!

Comment: Need to use this new app password just instead your previos password

Comment: Correct dear you need to use app password

Comment: works for me thans

Answer (score 1):

i had **logged to gitHub with access token**
and it had expired.

so i fumbled here.

**solution:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me,  I just closed Andriod Studio and re-opened and that's it the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
git config --global --unset http.proxy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my token has expired... I didn't notice that the expiration was set for 7 days

Answer (score 0):

For Android Chipmunk:

1. File
2. Invalidate Caches
3. Invalidate and restart

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because android studio cannot read credentials due to some problem or your [github token credentials has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72509956/13511570)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120198/13511570) works, but this approach also helps if you're already using GitHub token based authentication  :

1. Go to in AndroidStudio -> File -> Settings -> GitHub -> Remove the account
2. Generate a new github token or [update the existing one](https://github.com/settings/tokens/)
3. Add account again in AndroidStudio -> File -> Settings -> GitHub, Apply and Save
4. Invalidate caches and Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to remove GitHub credentials from the **window credentials.** then your right GitHub username and password.
you can find the window credentials in the control penal.
this issue occurs when the GitHub username or password is wrong mentioned in window credentials.